# Limit of definite integral using L’Hôpital’s rule

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

$$\Large
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^x\sin^{-1}t\,dt
$$

I am trying to calculate this limit. Using L’Hôpital’s rule, I am getting it as $1/4$, but the book says it's $3/8$. I don't know where I am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You probably computed wrongly the derivative of the integral with the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x/2}^x\arcsin t\,dt=
\arcsin x-\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\frac{x}{2}
$$
(I prefer not to use the notation $\sin^{-1}$ that I consider wrong).

Thus, after the first application of L’Hôpital, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\arcsin x-\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin x\cos x}
$$
and you can go on once more:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x/2)^2}}}{2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The function$\;\arcsin x\;$ is a continuous one so it has a primitive function, say $\;F(x)\;:\;\;F'(x)=\arcsin x\;$ , and thus by the FTC:

$$\int_{x/2}^x\arcsin t\,dt=F(x)-F\left(\frac x2\right)$$

Observe that $\;F(0)-F(0)=0-0=0\;$ , so we can now use l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)-F\left(\frac x2\right)}{\sin^2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F'(x)-\frac12F'\left(\frac x2\right)}{\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arcsin x-\frac12\arcsin\frac x2}{\sin 2x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac14\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}}}{2\cos 2x}=\frac{1-\frac14}{2}=\frac38$$